# XEN core login process

Tags: xml-rpc, xen, xenapp

I want to know how the xml-rpc works in xen core. I want the sample xml formate sent to xen core while login from XenCenter. Can anyone help me with that? I am not willing to use API provided by xen, I think we can make a connection via traditional http post. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing how I make it work.

This is the xml formate you need to provide for login in XEN SERVER. So make XML as XEN SERVER expects and make a connection and post the xml. It will return the expected response.

```
<?xml version=’1.0’?> <methodCall>
  <methodName>session.login_with_password</methodName> <params>
    <param>
      <value><string>user</string></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value><string>passwd</string></value> </param>
    </params>
  </methodCall>
```

it you return a XML like

```
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>Status</name>
            <value>Success</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>Value</name>
            <value>OpaqueRef:XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX</value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

Then parse the XML to get the data and save necessary data for further use. You can have a good idea about XML formate and return type from [XEN API Documentation](http://downloads.xen.org/Wiki/XenAPI/xenapi-1.0.6.pdf)

Best of luck. And feel free to ask any question.